# Webkit scroll performance on iOS browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, performance

I've inherited a website project with the task of making it perform better on mobile (particularly iOS). The site is very slow on scroll and parts of the page take a long time to load. I've tried most of the scroll fixes like -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; and transform: translate3d(0,0,0); but have not had any luck. I've also tried to dig into the rendering tools in Chrome Dev Tools on desktop to see if anything stuck out. I'm at a loss.

Here's the link: http://www.seacoastsciencecenter.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the Chrome Web Profiler to determine what is eating up so much CPU. Note that this is probably taking much longer on mobile.

[image: Chrome Web Profiler]

It looks like in your case, skrollr.min.js is taking up the most CPU, so I'd try to get rid of that and stick to built-in scrolling methods. Is there any reason you need a special library for scrolling?

Comment: Neat, I didn't know about the Chrome Web Profiler. The skrollr library is helping with some parallax icons on the home page. I'm looking to replace it if it's the culprit. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. If this helps you, please accept the answer. Thanks!